# android SMS Read permission Issue

Tags: android

I have get this error from my google play store account

> We only allow apps to access Call Log or SMS data for permitted uses
>   and only to enable the app’s core functionality.

I did implement with ***SmsRetrieverClient***. But my issue is ask reformat that the sms from server side 
EG :

> <#> Your ExampleApp code is: 123ABC78 FA+9qCX9VSu

Is there any way to do this without the reformatting

Comment: Have you removed the sms/contact permission declaration from your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

google has change policy, according new policy our app should not use system permission.(Like SMS, CALL). you have to request for it or fill permission form about app uses.

Answer (score 0):

Description available on android.developer.com blogs for SMS and Call Permission

You can refer that blog from below Link

[developer.android.com SMS and Call](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/reminder-smscall-log-policy-changes.html)

However, Google provide alternate way to read SMS for phone number verification.

[Alternate solution for SMS and Call permission](https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-sms-call-log-permissions-now-what-9b8226de7827)